# How to have a default font applied to all element on material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

When I create a "dumb" html element within a MUI component, for instance:

```
<Dialog>
   <p>I'm just a simple p</p>
   <div>I'm just a simple div</div>
</Dialog>
```

it doesn't apply the font of the style. It does work for some MUI elements (eg labels), but not others (Box) and not on dumb html elements either

Is it possible to configure MUI to apply the typography defined in the theme to every dom element?

Comment: Are you using [CssBaseline](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/#typography)?

Comment: Aaah, thanks! is there a way to apply CassBaseLine to some elements only ? the react part is embedded into an existing page